# How to select option in dropdown using Selenium in Python (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, selenium, driver, dropdown

I am trying to select dropdown year of 2021 on (https://www.theknot.com/registry/couplesearch) and am unable to figure out how to use the dropdown.

```
#This code is working
typetextfirst = driver.find_element_by_id("couples-search-first-name")
typetextfirst.clear()
typetextfirst.send_keys(row["First"])
typetextlast = driver.find_element_by_id("couples-search-last-name")
typetextlast.clear()
typetextlast.send_keys(row["Last"])


typetextyear = driver.find_element_by_id("couples-search-year")
#None of these options work to populate the year
typetextyear.selectByIndex(1)
typetextyear.select_by_index(1)
typetextyear.selectByVisibleText("2021")
typetextyear.select_by_visible_text("2021")

#This code is working
typetextlast.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it doesn't use standard dropdown widget but some widget created with `button` and `ul` and maybe you should click it and use key `arrow down` to move to selected year and send `ENTER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page doesn't use standard `dropdown` widget but it uses `button` and `ul` to emulate `dropdown`.

This code works for me on `Firefox` and `Chrome` on Linux Mint.

First I click `button` to open `dropdown` created with `ul` and later I search `li` with expected text and click it.

Because it may have text `2021` with some `spaces`/`tabs`/`enters` (which browser doesn't show) so I prefer `contains` instead of `=`

```
from selenium import webdriver
             
url = 'https://www.theknot.com/registry/couplesearch'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

year_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id("couples-search-year")
year_dropdown.click()

year = year_dropdown.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[contains(text(), '2021')]")
#year = year_dropdown.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[text()='2021']")
year.click()
```